# Library to convert any number to a metric expression

Tags: c#, .net

For a small personal [project](https://github.com/aloisdg/Doccou), I was looking to write a number as a human readable number. For example:

```
1023 -> 1K
12345678 -> 12M
```

Stack Exchange, like a lot of others websites, use the same trick. It is called [metric prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix).

Humanizer is a library to convert data in a human readable form. Since my feature match with their needs, I submitted a Pull Request (without answer for now). Meanwhile, I would love a feedback on my code.

What do you think of it? How can I improve it? This is the first time I have used XML doc. How is it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Humanizer
{
/// <summary>
/// Contains extension methods for changing a number to Metric representation (ToMetric)
/// and from Metric representation back to the number (FromMetric)
/// </summary>
public static class MetricNumeralExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Symbols is a list of every symbols for the Metric system.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly char[][] Symbols =
    {
        new[] { 'k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E', 'Z', 'Y' },
        new[] { 'm', '\u03bc', 'n', 'p', 'f', 'a', 'z', 'y' }
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Names link a Metric symbol (as key) to its name (as value).
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// We dont support :
    /// {'h', "hecto"},
    /// {'da', "deca" }, // !string
    /// {'d', "deci" },
    /// {'c', "centi"},
    /// </remarks>
    private static readonly Dictionary<char, string> Names = new Dictionary<char, string>()
    {
        {'Y', "yotta" }, {'Z', "zetta" }, {'E', "exa" }, {'P', "peta" }, {'T', "tera" }, {'G', "giga" }, {'M', "mega" }, {'k', "kilo" },
        {'m', "milli" }, {'μ', "micro" }, {'n', "nano" }, {'p', "pico" }, {'f', "femto" }, {'a', "atto" }, {'z', "zepto" }, {'y', "yocto" }
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a Metric representation into a number.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// We don't support input in the format {number}{name} nor {number} {name}.
    /// We only provide a solution for {number}{symbol} and {number} {symbol}.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="input">Metric representation to convert to a number</param>
    /// <example>
    /// "1k".FromMetric() => 1000d
    /// "123".FromMetric() => 123d
    /// "100m".FromMetric() => 1E-1
    /// </example>
    /// <returns>A number after a conversion from a Metric representation.</returns>
    public static double FromMetric(this string input)
    {
        if (input == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
        input = input.Trim();
        input = ReplaceNameBySymbol(input);
        if (input.Length == 0 || input.IsInvalidMetricNumeral())
            throw new ArgumentException("Empty or invalid Metric string.", "input");
        input = input.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
        var last = input[input.Length - 1];
        if (!Char.IsLetter(last)) return Double.Parse(input);
        Func<char[], double> getExponent = symbols => (symbols.IndexOf(last) + 1) * 3;
        var number = Double.Parse(input.Remove(input.Length - 1));
        var exponent = Math.Pow(10, Symbols[0].Contains(last) ? getExponent(Symbols[0]) : -getExponent(Symbols[1]));
        return number * exponent;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Replace every symbol's name by its symbol representation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">Metric representation with a name or a symbol</param>
    /// <returns>A metric representation with a symbol</returns>
    private static string ReplaceNameBySymbol(string input)
    {
        return Names.Aggregate(input, (current, name) => current.Replace(name.Value, name.Key.ToString()));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a number into a valid and Human-readable Metric representation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Inspired by a snippet from Thom Smith.
    /// <see cref="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181024/formatting-a-number-with-a-metric-prefix"/>
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="input">Number to convert to a Metric representation.</param>
    /// <param name="isSplitedBySpace">True will split the number and the symbol with a whitespace.</param>
    /// <param name="useSymbol">True will use symbol instead of name</param>
    /// <example>
    /// 1000d.ToMetric() => "1k"
    /// 123d.ToMetric() => "123"
    /// 1E-1.ToMetric() => "100m"
    /// </example>
    /// <returns>A valid Metric representation</returns>
    public static string ToMetric(this double input, bool isSplitedBySpace = false, bool useSymbol = true)
    {
        if (input.Equals(0)) return input.ToString();
        if (input.IsOutOfRange()) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("input");
        var exponent = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(input)) / 3);
        if (exponent == 0) return input.ToString();
        var number = input * Math.Pow(1000, -exponent);
        var symbol = Math.Sign(exponent) == 1 ? Symbols[0][exponent - 1] : Symbols[1][-exponent - 1];
        return number
            + (isSplitedBySpace ? " " : String.Empty)
            + GetUnit(symbol, useSymbol);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a number into a valid and Human-readable Metric representation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Inspired by a snippet from Thom Smith.
    /// <see cref="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181024/formatting-a-number-with-a-metric-prefix"/>
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="input">Number to convert to a Metric representation.</param>
    /// <param name="isSplitedBySpace">True will split the number and the symbol with a whitespace.</param>
    /// <param name="useSymbol">True will use symbol instead of name</param>
    /// <example>
    /// 1000.ToMetric() => "1k"
    /// 123.ToMetric() => "123"
    /// 1E-1.ToMetric() => "100m"
    /// </example>
    /// <returns>A valid Metric representation</returns>
    public static string ToMetric(this int input, bool isSplitedBySpace = false, bool useSymbol = true)
    {
        return Convert.ToDouble(input).ToMetric(isSplitedBySpace, useSymbol);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the unit from a symbol of from the symbol's name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="symbol">The symbol linked to the unit</param>
    /// <param name="useSymbol">True will use symbol instead of name</param>
    /// <returns>A symbol or a symbol's name</returns>
    private static string GetUnit(char symbol, bool useSymbol)
    {
        return useSymbol ? symbol.ToString() : Names[symbol];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if a Metric representation is out of the valid range.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">A Metric representation who might be out of the valid range.</param>
    /// <returns>True if input is out of the valid range.</returns>
    private static bool IsOutOfRange(this double input)
    {
        const int limit = 27;
        var bigLimit = Math.Pow(10, limit);
        var smallLimit = Math.Pow(10, -limit);
        Func<double, double, bool> outside = (min, max) => !(max > input && input > min);
        return (Math.Sign(input) == 1 && outside(smallLimit, bigLimit))
               || (Math.Sign(input) == -1 && outside(-bigLimit, -smallLimit));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if a string is not a valid Metric representation.
    /// A valid representation is in the format "{0}{1}" or "{0} {1}"
    /// where {0} is a number and {1} is an allowed symbol.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// ToDo: Performance: Use (string input, out number) to escape the double use of Parse()
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="input">A string who might contain a invalid Metric representation.</param>
    /// <returns>True if input is not a valid Metric representation.</returns>
    private static bool IsInvalidMetricNumeral(this string input)
    {
        double number;
        var index = input.Length - 1;
        var last = input[index];
        var isSymbol = Symbols[0].Contains(last) || Symbols[1].Contains(last);
        return !Double.TryParse(isSymbol ? input.Remove(index) : input, out number);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of the specified Unicode
    /// character in this string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="chars">The string containing the value.</param>
    /// <param name="value">A Unicode character to seek.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The zero-based index position of value if that character is found, or -1 if it is not.
    /// </returns>
    private static int IndexOf(this ICollection<char> chars, char value)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < chars.Count; i++)
            if (chars.ElementAt(i).Equals(value))
                return i;
        return -1;
    }
}
}
```

The class is self-contained and documented but if you want more information, feel free to ask for it.

Comment: Do you ever plan on modifying the `Names` dictionary during runtime? If not, make it an `IReadOnlyDictionary`

Comment: Since I used the keyword "readonly", I want it to be readonly. So lets use a IReadOnlyDictionary. Thank you for the input.

Comment: @BradM I cannot use IReadOnlyDictionary. I am using a PCL project and It might not be supported.

Comment: This code and updates are available at mine: [Humanizer's fork](https://github.com/aloisdg/Humanizer/blob/metric/src/Humanizer/MetricNumeralExtensions.cs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you specifically asked about doc comments, I love that you provided examples.

> ```
> /// <example>
> /// "1k".FromMetric() => 1000d
> /// "123".FromMetric() => 123d
> /// "100m".FromMetric() => 1E-1
> /// </example>
> /// <returns>A number after a conversion from a Metric representation.</returns>
> public static double FromMetric(this string input)
> ```

But you missed something important. This won't render as code when you run it through Sandcastle or Doxygen. You have to wrap it in the `<code>` element for it to render properly post processing.

This is the proper way to create example documentation.

```
/// <example>
/// ...maybe some plain text...
/// <code>
/// ...some example code here...
/// </ code>
/// </ example>
```

---

Just a general comment about the code itself; it's ***dense***. Like, *really* dense. The readability would be greatly improved if you used more vertical white space.

Comment: `<code>` added, I didn't know. I never use Sandcastle or Doxygen in . NET.  I don't find it dense, but I trust you. I added some vertical white space and splited `ToMetric` and `FromMetric()` in smaller functions. Can I update my original post? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @aloisdg Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.